# Sharing a cookie between multiple apps on localhost

Tags: node.js, cookies

My **API** (localhost:8080) issues cookies for my **frontend** (localhost:3000). The cookies domains are set to "NULL" on development mode.

I have another **small frontend** (localhost:9000) on the side. It will be deployed as a subdomain of the **frontend** in production, so I shouldn't have issue.

In development, I have found no way to request the **API** from my **small frontend**, I have no CORS issues but my API throws 401 because the **small frontend** isn't sending the cookie. The "Send For" attribute is set to "Any type of connection". The cookie is set to expire in a year. I checked in the browser settings, on both ports the cookie is there with the same settings and content.

On the **small frontend** I can list the cookies on document.cookie but trying to retrieve any value from the cookie using either

```
function getCookie(key) {
   var keyValue = document.cookie.match('(^|;) ?' + key + '=([^;]*)(;|$)');
   return keyValue ? keyValue[2] : null;
}
getCookie('sid');
```

OR

```
$.cookie('sid');
```

Doesn't work.

Setting the cookie domain to **NULL** doesn't work.
Setting the cookie domain to **localhost** doesn't do the trick either and it isn't supported by chrome. ([see this](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-bugs/4HFLDhvvXsc)) It is supported on FF but I have the same issues

I have tried to set the cookies domain to ".app.localhost" and then set in /etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1:8080 api.app.localhost
127.0.0.1:9000 app.app.localhost
127.0.0.1:3000 front.app.localhost
```

But I couldn't access my apps.
I think I missing something big here.

**EDIT:**

About the /etc/hosts file

After some digging I found out that ports cannot be specified on ips

However, you can set it up this way:

```
127.0.0.1 api.app.localhost:8080
127.0.0.1 app.app.localhost:3000
127.0.0.1 app2.app.localhost:9000
```

I can access and login on my app.app.localhost:3000 with the cookie set to `.app.localhost`, when I go to app.app.localhost:9000 I can see that there is a cookie containing my sessionId setup with `.app.localhost` as domain and `Any kind of connection`.

Yet, same issue as explained above.